# type-check error after upgrading to Xcode 10

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10

After upgrading to Xcode 10 and building my code

```
let nearestWedge: Int = Int(round(((currentRadians + (radiansPerWedge / 2)) + snappingPositionRadians) / radiansPerWedge))
```

I got this error:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Comment: What is the error? Add more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appears when the swift compiler finds the expression too heavy to calculate it in a reasonable time

just break your expression in sub expression; one example could be:

```
let firstHalfOfExpression = (currentRadians + (radiansPerWedge / 2)) + snappingPositionRadians
let nearestWedge: Int = Int(round(firstHalf / radiansPerWedge))
```

Comment: my code used to work perfectly before I updated my version of Xcode.

Comment: why you should? it's just make code more readable. You can't bypass the compiler error. Anyway, now compiles?

Comment: why you can't??

Comment: just simply break your expressions again it's also more readable and maintainable: 
`let ballPositionX = ball.position.x
        let ballWidth = ball.size.width / 2
        let goldZone2Position = goldZone2.position.x + goldZone2.size.width / 2
        let goldZone1Position = goldZone1.position.x - goldZone1.size.width / 2
        if(ballPositionX - ballWidth >= goldZonePosition && ballPositionX + ballWidth <= goldZone1Position) { }`

Comment: @Devlax Please mark this as correct answer. since solves the problem